# Spring AOP The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'

Tags: spring, aop

Line 13 in XML document from class path resource [ApplicationContextAOP.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element **'aop:config'**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

```
<bean id="audience" class="com.idol.Audience" />

<aop:config>
<aop:aspect ref="audience">

    <!-- Before performance -->     

    <aop:before pointcut="execution(*com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..))"
    method="takeSeats"/>

    <aop:before pointcut="execution(*com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..))"
    method="turnOffCellPhones" />

    <!-- After performance -->  

    <aop:after-returning pointcut="execution(*com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..))"
    method="applaud" />

    <!-- After bad performance(exception thrown) -->    

    <aop:after-throwing pointcut="execution(*com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..))"
    method="demandRefund" />

</aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="poeticDuke" class="com.idol.performers.PoeticJuggler">
<constructor-arg value = "15" />
<constructor-arg ref = "sonnet29" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

I've seen similar error and I am pretty sure my classpath has org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M2.jar

Could you tell me please what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you very much for your question. I was facing the same problem, but in my case the problem was that I was missing `spring-aop.jar` in the classpath; that was what I was missing. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to add to your schemaLocation:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
...
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
...
"
```

Comment: Now I get this one :-( Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [ApplicationContextAOP.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

Comment: You're missing the [aopalliance jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|aopalliance|aopalliance|1.0|jar).

Comment: @Aubergine: You should accept this answer as the correct answer and ask a new question.

Comment: Did that, sorry it just takes too long to set it up - loosing patience.

Answer (score 4):

```
Adding one more possibility to the earlier provided answers : 

Wrong version of schemaLocation:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/ 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 

Correct Version:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd

REASON: The extra "/" after "schema/aop"
```

Answer (score 0):

We received the similar error message for the element `tx:advice` and got it resolved by replacing the `org.springframework.*-3.0.0.M3.jar`s with `org.springframework.*-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar`s where `*` represents the jar modules. Hence, try getting a stable release to fix the similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me with the following schema definition file. The cause was the extra > after `spring-aop-3.0.xsd`. Solved after removing it.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd>
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd">

<!--    reference to tht jdbc name space and schema definition file-->

    <!--    to enable AspectJ support-->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    
 </beans>
```